# Find the domain and range of $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2+x+1})$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

Find the domain and range of $f(x)=\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2+x+1})$

**Finding the domain:**

$$x^2+x+1>=0 \text { it is always true }$$

$$-1<=\sqrt{x^2+x+1}<=1$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}>=-1 \text { and } \sqrt{x^2+x+1}<=1$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+x+1}<=1$$
$$x^2+x+1<=1$$
$$x(x+1)<=0$$
$$x\in[-1,0]$$

**Finding the range**

$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\left([-1,0]+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}
{4}}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\left[\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]^2+\frac{3}
{4}}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]+\frac{3}
{4}}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\left[\frac{3}{4},1\right]}\right)$$
$$f(x)=\sin^{-1}\left({\left[\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},1\right]}\right)$$
$$f(x)\in \left[2m\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{3},2m\pi+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right] \text { where m is integer }$$

but actual answer is $\left[\dfrac{\pi}{3},\dfrac{\pi}{2}\right]$

Answer (score 1):

> $$f(x)\in \left[2m\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{3},2m\pi+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}\right] \text { where m is integer }$$

This isn't true because the range of the inverse sine function is from $\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. Let $$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$$
then
$$\sin{\theta}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
with the restriction that $\theta\in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right]$. The possible triangles with this ratio of $y$ to hypotenuse (i.e. $\sin$) are shown below

[image]

where only $\pi/ 3$ falls within the restricted range for the inverse sine function. Similarly, letting

$$\theta=\sin^{-1}\left(1\right)$$

means

$$\sin{\theta}=1$$

where only $ \pi/ 2$ falls within the restricted range for the inverse sine function.

Answer (score 0):

The range of $f(x)=sin^{-1} x$ is $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ over the domain $[-1,1]$.
So here  range the range of the the given function  is $[\pi/3,\pi/2].$

Comment: but see if $y=\sin^{-1}x$, then $\sin y=x$, so in this question $\sin(f(x))=\left[\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},1\right]$, so you can see that $y\in[2m\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{3},2m\pi+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}]$ where $m\in Z$, what am I missing here

Answer (score 0):

The range of the function $\sin^{-1}$ is only $[-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2}]$. Hence with $f(x) = \sin^{-1} \left( \left[ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, 1\right] \right)$, the $\sin^{-1}$ functions maps these points to the range $\left[ \frac{\pi}{3}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right]$.

Comment: but see if $y=\sin^{-1}x$, then $\sin y=x$, so in this question $\sin(f(x))=\left[\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2},1\right]$, so you can see that $y\in[2m\pi+\dfrac{\pi}{3},2m\pi+\dfrac{2\pi}{3}]$ where $m\in Z$, what am I missing here

Comment: You are correct in saying that all of these y values give a sine value in the expected range. However, the $\sin ^ {-1}$ function has a range only in $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, by definition. The reason for this is that otherwise, it will become a multi-valued function, which is not allowed. A function cannot be multi-valued.

Comment: good point, thanks

Answer (score -1):

The domain of $$f(x)=\sin^{-1}(\sqrt{x^2+x+1})$$ is where you get $$0\le x^2+x+1\le 1$$ which is the interval $[-1,0]$

Note that $f(-1/2)=\pi/3$ is the minimum value and $f(-1)=f(0)= \pi/2$ is the maximum.

Thus the range is the interval  $[\pi/3, \pi/2]$